# Image doesn't update when written to.. weird goings on

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, emgucv

I have a Kinect WPF Application that takes images from the Kinect, does some feature detection using EmguCV (A C# opencv wrapper) and displays the output on the using a WPF image.

I have had this working before, but the application now refuses to update the screen image when the imagesource is written to, but I have not changed the way it works.

the Image(called video) is written to as such:

`video.Source = bitmapsource;`

in the colorframeready event handler.

This works fine until I introduce some opencv code before the imagesource is written to. It does not matter what source is used, so I don't think it is a conflict there. I have narrowed down the offending EmguCV code to this line:

`RecentKeyPoints = surfCPU.DetectKeyPointsRaw(ImageRecent, null);`

which jumps straight into the opencv code. It is worth noting that:

- ImageRecent has completely different origins to the bitmapsource updating the screen.
- Reading video.Source returns the bitmapsource, so it seems to be writing correctly, just not updating the screen.

Let me know if you want any more information...

```
void nui_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    // Checks for a recent Depth Image
    if (!TrackingReady) return;

    // Stores image
    using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (colorImageFrame != null)
        {
            if (FeatureTracker.ColourImageRecent == null)
                //allocate the first time
                FeatureTracker.ColourImageRecent = new byte[colorImageFrame.PixelDataLength];

            colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(FeatureTracker.ColourImageRecent);
        }
        else return;
    }

    FeatureTracker.FeatureDetect(nui);

    //video.Source = FeatureTracker.ColourImageRecent.ToBitmapSource();
    video.Source = ((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("test1.png")).ToBitmapSource();

    TrackingReady = false;
}

public Bitmap FeatureDetect(KinectSensor nui)
{
    byte[] ColourClone = new byte[ColourImageRecent.Length];
    Array.Copy(ColourImageRecent, ColourClone, ColourImageRecent.Length);
    Bitmap test = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("test1.png");

    test.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);

    Image<Gray, Byte> ImageRecent = new Image<Gray, byte>(test);
    SURFDetector surfCPU = new SURFDetector(2000, false);
    VectorOfKeyPoint RecentKeyPoints;
    Matrix<int> indices;
    Matrix<float> dist;
    Matrix<byte> mask;
    bool MatchFailed = false;

    // extract SURF features from the object image
    RecentKeyPoints = surfCPU.DetectKeyPointsRaw(ImageRecent, null);
    //Matrix<float> RecentDescriptors = surfCPU.ComputeDescriptorsRaw(ImageRecent, null, RecentKeyPoints);
    //MKeyPoint[] RecentPoints = RecentKeyPoints.ToArray();

    // don't feature detect on first attempt, just store image details for next attempt
    #region
    /*
    if (KeyPointsOld == null)
    {
        KeyPointsOld = RecentKeyPoints;
        PointsOld = RecentPoints;
        DescriptorsOld = RecentDescriptors;
        return ImageRecent.ToBitmap();
    }
    */
    #endregion

    // Attempt to match points to their nearest neighbour
    #region
    /*
    BruteForceMatcher SURFmatcher = new BruteForceMatcher(BruteForceMatcher.DistanceType.L2F32);
    SURFmatcher.Add(RecentDescriptors);
    int k = 5;
    indices = new Matrix<int>(DescriptorsOld.Rows, k);
    dist = new Matrix<float>(DescriptorsOld.Rows, k);
    */

    // Match features, provide the top k matches
    //SURFmatcher.KnnMatch(DescriptorsOld, indices, dist, k, null);

    // Create mask and set to allow all features
    //mask = new Matrix<byte>(dist.Rows, 1);
    //mask.SetValue(255);
    #endregion

    //Features2DTracker.VoteForUniqueness(dist, 0.8, mask);

    // Check number of good maches and for error and end matching if true
    #region
    //int nonZeroCount = CvInvoke.cvCountNonZero(mask);
    //if (nonZeroCount < 5) MatchFailed = true;
    /*
    try
    {
        nonZeroCount = Features2DTracker.VoteForSizeAndOrientation(RecentKeyPoints, KeyPointsOld, indices, mask, 1.5, 20);
    }
    catch (SystemException)
    {
        MatchFailed = true;
    }
    if (nonZeroCount < 5) MatchFailed = true;

    if (MatchFailed)
    {
        return ImageRecent.ToBitmap();
    }
    */
    #endregion

    //DepthMapColourCoordsRecent = CreateDepthMap(nui, DepthImageRecent);
    //PointDist[] FeatureDistances = DistanceToFeature(indices, mask, RecentPoints);
    //Image<Rgb,Byte> rgbimage = ImageRecent.Convert<Rgb, Byte>();
    //rgbimage = DrawPoints(FeatureDistances, rgbimage);

    // Store recent image data for next feature detect.
    //KeyPointsOld = RecentKeyPoints;
    //PointsOld = RecentPoints;
    //DescriptorsOld = RecentDescriptors;

    //CreateDepthMap(nui, iva);
    //rgbimage = CreateDepthImage(DepthMapColourCoordsRecent, rgbimage);

    // Convert image back to a bitmap
    count++;
    //Bitmap bitmap3 = rgbimage.ToBitmap();
    //bitmapstore = bitmap3;

    //bitmap3.Save("test" + count.ToString() + ".png");

    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you do a diff in your source control commits?

Comment: I could but I don't think it would help, there were a lot of changes as a result of Microsoft changing the kinect API. This part of the code however has not changed.

If you comment out the surfCPU method call above though, it works, but if it is left uncommented it does not. Even a general answer about how one part of code can affect an unrelated part in .net would be great as a point in the right direction

Comment: showing your code better would help. in any event just start removing chunks of code and replacing them with mock objects until you narrow it down..

Comment: Added code. Yes, have been doing that, hence the majority of FeatureDetect() is commented out! Thanks for the advice, I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I had a similar problem and thought I'd share my solution.

In my case I was processing the depth stream. The default resolution was 640x480, and Emgu just wasn't able to process the image fast enough to keep up with the frameready handler. As soon as I reduced the depth stream resolution to 320x240 the problem went away.

I also went a bit further and moved my image processing to a different thread which sped it up even more (do a search for ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle). I'm still not able to do 640x480 at a reasonable frame rate, but at least the image renders so I can see what's going on.